# How can I execute a php file from command line which uses class from different namespace?

Tags: php, composer-php

I'm trying to make a file which you can execute from command line to create tables in a database. The problem is, that file uses a class from a different namespace, so when I try to run `php migrations.php`, I get `Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class "Core\Database\Database" not found in C:\Users\user\Desktop\app\migrations.php:6`.

I am using composer's autoloader and I have no issues with other files - this only happens when I try to execute the mentioned file from command line.

I can solve it by requiring the file which contains the class used, but then I get the same error just in another file, since that other file also uses classes from different namespaces.

`migrations.php`

```
<?php

use Core\Database\Database;

Database::query("CREATE TABLE real_estates(
    id INT(11) UNSIGNED AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
    name VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    city_id INT(11) NOT NULL,
    area INT(11) NOT NULL,
    price INT(11) NOT NULL,
    description TEXT NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT `fk_real_estate_city`
        FOREIGN KEY (city_id) REFERENCES cities (id)
        ON DELETE RESTRICT
        ON UPDATE RESTRICT
)");

Database::query("CREATE TABLE cities(
    id INT(11) UNSIGNED AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
    name VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL
)");
```

`composer.json`

```
{
  "autoload": {
    "classmap": [
      "./"
    ]
  },
  "require": {
    "ext-pdo": "*"
  }
}
```

Comment: Most probably you need to write additional autoloader for custom namespace(s). Optionally if it's single external class just tru to `require_once()` it.

Comment: Where **exactly** are you using the autoloader?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to `require` the composer's autoload file manually, usually this done by your web application.

```
require_once  pathOfComposerAutoloadFile.php
```

Comment: Ah, yes. I did require it in my `index.php`, but I forgot to do so in the mentioned file. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Create an autoload.php and include all required file in this file like....

```
include(__DIR__ . 'yourfile.php');
```

Use this autoload.php in your migration.php file.
Now you can run migration.php from url or command line.